# Picture gallery with django

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, django

I created a image gallery using JS, CSS, and HTML to extract data from a JSON file, which I created, then set up tiles and modals for each image. It works perfectly, but then I was told to convert it to the Django framework to make it maintainable by non-coders. I have no experience with Django, so I have idea where to even start with this.

Here is part of the gallery:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XMRf.jpg

Here is a sample modal:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JvhD.png

Note: these are just filler images and text.

When the page loads, it parses out the JSON and sets up the code for the tiles.   Then it creates a modal for each tile.

Are there any references or tutorials I can look at to get what I want?  Or will I just have to completely change how my page works?

Comment: It sounds like you need to write a user interface to create your JSON file. Django is a framework that allows you to write web applications. So you could create a webpage that your users login to and add pictures. You add those picture-entries to a database or your JSON file directly.
If you search for "django beginner tutorials" you'll find lots of reading material. If your application is that small take a look at the python "flask" framework. If python is your way to go...

Comment: If you want it maintainable by non-coders, and as a new Django user yourself, I'm not sure it's your best bet. You would need to incorporate some sort of CMS so the maintainers wouldn't need to know HTML, CSS, and JS. I think Wordpress, or related, would be your best bet. Everything is already packaged in there for you.